# Transitive bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a vertex-transitive bipartite graph. Then is $G$ Hamiltonian-connected?

A graph is **Hamiltonian-connected** if for every pair of vertices there is a Hamiltonian path between the two vertices.

Comment: What does it mean for a graph to be "transitive"?

Comment: @Gerry: The automorphism group of the graph acts transitively on the set of vertices.

Comment: @Brian, thanks. When I posted the comment, the question read, "transitive", not "vertex-transitive".

Comment: @user108209: Why need $G$ be connected at all? Just consider two disconnected cycles of length $4$ which constitute already a bipartite vertex-transitive graph.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Can a bipartite graph ever be Hamiltonian-connected? Any path must bounce back and forth between the parts.

Comment: Can you explain more? how can I use this fact for every vertices there is a $f\in Aut(G)$ s.t f carries one point to another.

Comment: @user108209: The point of the hint is that vertex-transitivity is irrelevant: you can ignore it. Just prove that no bipartite graph is Hamiltonian-connected.